# Insert python variable value into SQL table

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

I have a password system that stores the password for a python program in an SQL table. I want the user to be able to change the password in a tkinter window but I am not sure how to use the value of a python variable as the value for the SQL table. Here is a sample code:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('testDataBase')
c = conn.cursor()

c.execute("INSERT INTO info Values('test')")
c.execute("SELECT password FROM info")
password = (c.fetchone()[0])

#Window setup
admin = tkinter.Tk()
admin.minsize(width=800, height = 600)
admin.maxsize(width=800, height = 600)
#GUI
passwordChangeLabel = Label(admin, text="It is recommended to change your password after first login!", font=("Arial", 14))
passwordChangeLabel.pack()

passwordChangeCurrentPasswordLabel = Label(admin, text="Current Password: ", font=("Arial", 11))
passwordChangeCurrentPasswordLabel.place(x=275, y=30)
passwordChangeCurrentPasswordEntry = Entry(admin)
passwordChangeCurrentPasswordEntry.place(x=405, y=32.5)

passwordChangeNewPasswordLabel = Label(admin, text="New Password: ", font=("Arial", 11))
passwordChangeNewPasswordLabel.place(x=295, y=50)
passwordChangeNewPasswordEntry = Entry(admin)
passwordChangeNewPasswordEntry.place(x=405, y=52.5)

passwordChangeButton = Button(admin, text="Submit", width=20)
passwordChangeButton.place(x=350, y=80)

def changePasswordFunction(event):
    newPassword = passwordChangeNewPasswordEntry.get()
    enteredPassword = passwordChangeCurrentPasswordEntry.get()
    if enteredPassword == password:
        c.execute("REPLACE INTO info(password) VALUES(newPassword)")
    else:
        wrong = tkinter.Toplevel()
        wrong.minsize(width=200, height = 100)
        wrong.maxsize(width=200, height = 100)
        Label(wrong, text="Sorry that password is incorrect!", font=("Arial", 24), anchor=W, wraplength=180, fg="red").pack()

admin.bind('<Return>', changePasswordFunction)
passwordChangeButton.bind('<Button-1>', changePasswordFunction)
```

This code will bring up an error:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: newPassword
```

How can I properly replace the previous value in the password column with the new entered password?

Comment: Have you read the documentation on parameterized queries? https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html

Answer (score -1):

There are two valid ways to use `VALUES()`: with a label or a string literal.  A string literal is a string in single or double quotes.

Since you didn't put `newPassword` in quotes, Sqlite assumes `newPassword` is a label, i.e. a column name.  It goes looking for the value of the `newPassword` field in the current record, and throws an error since that field doesn't exist.

What you want to do is, take the value of the `newPassword` python variable and put it in quotes.  Here's a corrected query string (not tested):

```
"REPLACE INTO info(password) VALUES('" + newPassword + "')"
```

As someone mentions in the comments, updating your database directly with user inputs is highly insecure.  Database interfaces generally provide easy ways to sanitize all inputs, and you should make it a point to follow those practices.  A great resource with code examples from many popular languages is [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/).  (Also note that failing to include information about SQL security in your answers at SO can result in down-votes.)

Comment: That works, second question (sorry I'm new to databases) Why do I need to insert my value into the table every time I run the program for it to be there? Is there a way to make a value remain in a table until it is deleted or replaced?

Comment: There is no reason the data wouldn't be there, unless you deleted it.  Chances are, you're making some kind of mistake in the way you query for it.  Your code doesn't show what fields are in the `info` table.  It's a good idea to have an auto-increment index field in your table, so that every row can be uniquely identified no matter what (i.e., even if two users have the same password).

Comment: This opens up the possibility to an sql injection attack. sqlite supports [parameterized statements](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html).